# How to exit .bat file after finish the task and terminate the task

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I using the code below in my bat file to get my pdf file and print it out via printer. But after printed the receipt adobe reader and my bat file does not exit how can i terminate it?

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t "C:\Users\user\Desktop\invoice\Receipt.pdf" "58MBIII"
```

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code, it's hard to say. If that _is_ the whole code, the script is waiting for Adobe Reader to close.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not so much the batch file commands but Acrobat Reader, whose later versions don't play nice with the command line: they leave a window open allegedly in case another document is opened next.

Some things to try:

- Use other PDF readers. There are plenty
- Investigate how to use the OLE `print` verb to print a file from the command line, which is what actually happens when right clicking on a file and selecting *Print*
- Search for "Print PDF From Command Line" for other ideas. For example, http://www.robvanderwoude.com/commandlineswitches.php#Acrobat contains some.